# Zooming for D3 parallel coordinates plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, parallel-coordinates

I am using parallel coordinates to display data from csv file.

My application require modifying the method of displaying data on the axes. For each value on axes, i need to draw a point (for example: circle with r=3). When I have duplicated values in the same axis, I need to draw a circle next to each other as illustrated in this picture:

[image]

Another requirement for my application is to provide a zoom function on axes, so that I can got a close view to specific points.

What i was thinking of, is to perform zooming by changing the height of axes using mouse wheel event to zoom in and out, and at the same time to increase the distance between the points.

Is there any idea how I can perform zooming by changing the height of axe by mouse event wheel without refreshing the page for every time i need to change its hight?

Comment: is there any example of zooming in parallel coordinates using D3?

Comment: @phs, may I ask you why did you rollback tag "parallel-coordinates". I will respects whatever you did, but I am curious why?

Comment: It was a new tag with no definition nor any followers; I thought it was spurious.  If there's real call for it, I won't veto it again.

Comment: Were you able to do Zoom in parallel axis?